# Why can i plug in an ethernet cable from the wall directly to the 1 gbps socket in my pc but not the 2.5 gbps one?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, power

Why does my Ethernet connection work when plugged into the 1 Gbps socket on my PC and directly into the wall, but not when connected to the 2.5 Gbps socket, using the same wall outlet?

Is it because the 2.5 gbps conn needs power which it gets from the router or somthing else is stopping it from working?

By not working i mean i get no internet at all, not a capped 1 gbps connection on the 2.5 gbps line. Mobo is meg x570 godlike.

Comment: What's on the other side? I'd guess almost that the router isn't dropping back to a 1 gig connection gracefully, but that's odd. Also is the link *up* but not working or is there no link?

Comment: Does your 2.5Gbps port work fine when you connect it to other things?

Comment: If you have 2 different ports, in order for those ports to work, they must be patched in the patch panel. Its quite likely that the port simply is not patched. Like putting a 3 socket power extension cord on the floor, but not plugging it in. Any device connected to it will not get power either. Because an office have more wall ports than the switch has ports, it is common to only patch what is needed, and only upgrade the switch to a larger one if all ports are in use. It may have been patched in the past, but when someone needed the 2.5 gbps port, they reused that one.

Comment: Check the Settings in the Killer control centre

Comment: the 2.5 gbps ethernet port on the mobo works when plugged into a router (the 2.5 gbps port and even the 1gbps port in the router).